# Closed Curve with different limits

Tags: complex-analysis

**NB Mods: I am asking about something entirely different about this question than I asked before**

[image]

[image]

Why is it that if i put in the limits $[0,2\pi]$ instead of $[-\pi,\pi]$ I get a different result $(-4 \sqrt{3}) $ given this is a closed curve?

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{\cdot}$?

Comment: $\sqrt z=\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt r\,e^{i\theta/2}\ .$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your working, you are using the following definition:
$$\sqrt z=\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt r\,e^{i\theta/2}\ .$$
Now consider, for example, the point
$$z=-3i\ ,$$
which is on your contour.  In calculating the integral as you have shown, the square root of this number will be
$$\sqrt z=\sqrt{3e^{-i\pi/2}}=\sqrt3\,e^{-i\pi/4}\ .$$
On the other hand, if you took the integral with $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, you would have to evaluate it as
$$\sqrt z=\sqrt{3e^{3i\pi/2}}=\sqrt3\,e^{3i\pi/4}\ ,$$
which is not the same as the above square root.  Therefore, if you evaluate the integrals
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt z\,dz\quad\hbox{and}\quad \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt z\,dz$$
by the method you have indicated, they are, despite appearances, the integrals of **two different functions**.  This is why they give different results.

Comment: OK but given the question as defined above how do I know which limits to use?

Comment: And i'm assuming you meant $z=-3i$ instead of $z=3i$?

Comment: @lemony9201 ooops... fixed.  Thanks for picking it up.

Comment: As far as I can see the only way you can know which limits to use is if you have been told exactly which definition of the square root to use.  For example, maybe, if you look further back in your text, it will say something like: the function $\sqrt z$ is defined by$$\sqrt z=\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt r\,e^{i\theta/2}\ ,\quad\hbox{where $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$}.$$Or maybe not... ;-(